# Disable button when clicked and make other buttons enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i have three buttons in my wpf window what is the best way to disable button when clicked and make other two button enabled

```
<Button Name="initialzeButton"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="460,0,0,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="initialzeButton_Click"
                    Content="Start"
                    Cursor="Hand" />
            <Button Name="uninitialzeButton"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="0,0,64,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="uninitialzeButton_Click"
                    Content="Stop"
                    Cursor="Hand" />
            <Button Name="loadButton"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="25"
                    Margin="0,0,9,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="loadButton_Click"
                    Content="Load"
                    Cursor="Hand" />
```

now i use this way in each button :(

```
      private void uninitialzeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {

            this.uninitialzeButton.IsEnabled = false;
            if (!this.initialzeButton.IsEnabled)
            {
                 this.initialzeButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            if (!this.loadButton.IsEnabled)
            {
                 this.loadButton.IsEnabled = true;
            }


      }
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of 'best way'? Is it quick and few lines of code or elegant or..

Several ways come into my mind:
- Use MVVM Light: 1 relaycommand for the three buttons, 3 dependency objects (properties in the viewmodel) for isEnabled which will all be set to false, only set isEnabled to true for the button clicked (which could be sent as a parameter in the relaycommand).
- Use booleanconverters/booleaninverterconverters on the isEnabled property.
- Restyle radiobutton to look like a button, replace the three buttons with a radiobutton group. When one radiobutton is selected, the other ones will be deselected, style them as disabled. Prevent deselected items from being clicked.

Regards,

Michel

Answer (score 0):

you can do somthing like this on page load -

```
PostBackOptions postBackOptions = new PostBackOptions(Button1);
            Button1.OnClientClick = "this.disabled=true;";
            Button1.OnClientClick += ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(postBackOptions);
```

Comment: this is for `button1_clcik`. You can add the same handler for other buttons

Comment: i think this for web project my project is wpf

Answer (score 0):

For a pure XAML solution wrap them in a style stripped ListBox and tie the click to selection, and selection to disabled state.